# Drupal 8 doesn't install date module

Tags: date, drupal, module

I tried to install the date module which is a requirement for many other modules and Drupal crashed with

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

drupal 8.3 runs on xamp.Apache error log showed me this:

```
[:error] [pid 4860:tid 1544] [client ::1:63066] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Extension\\InfoParserException: "Missing required keys (type, core, name) in temporary://update-extraction-577d1204/date/date_api/config/date_api.info.yml" at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\drupal\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Extension\\InfoParserDynamic.php line 29, referer: http://localhost/drupal/admin/modules/install
```

All other modules install just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 for Date datetime module exist in it's core.

On Drupal.org date module [date dev](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/date-8.x-1.x-dev.zip) version show, but when you download and open the date module folder then you see 
  In this folder not any **info.yml** file (that must needs for drupal 8 module development)

that's why may be you got this problem.